# Error: package ‘digest’ was installed by an R version with different internals; it needs to be reinstalled for use with this R version

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am hosting my shiny app on a Ubuntu 16.04 server in which I have also installed RStudio server. The welcome page of the shiny server can be accessed successfully with the demo-app on `localhost:3838`. But when I try to run a simple app (default shiny Old Faithful Geyser Data): `localhost:3838/test`, I get `An error has occurred The application failed to start`. The application exited during initialization.

This appeared after I upgraded from R.3.4 to 3.5.2

I have pulled out the a application log, and it says: `"Error: package ‘digest’ was installed by an R version with different internals; it needs to be reinstalled for use with this R version
Execution halted"`. I took the following steps but still the same error:

1. Uninstall the digest package completely from the directory path,  and re-install it.
2. uninstall rjava package and re-install
3. remove the entire shiny server and re-install

shiny-server.log:

```
[2019-02-13T12:03:33.048] [INFO] shiny-server - Starting listener on http://[::]:3838
[2019-02-13T12:14:20.757] [INFO] shiny-server - Error getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.
[2019-02-13T12:24:50.935] [INFO] shiny-server - Error getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.
[2019-02-13T12:25:32.009] [INFO] shiny-server - Error getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.
[2019-02-13T12:26:14.637] [INFO] shiny-server - Error getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.
[2019-02-13T12:30:02.063] [INFO] shiny-server - Error getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.
[2019-02-13T13:22:45.655] [INFO] shiny-server - Error getting worker: Error: The application exited during initialization.
```

shiny-application.log:

```
Error: package ‘digest’ was installed by an R version with different internals; it needs to be reinstalled for use with this R version
Execution halted
```

No package has failed or is failing to load, but the shiny application is just not working, giving the error. The expected output is a running app on shiny-server

Any possible Help?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issues. Where you able to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Running this code within R (using `sudo R` command in Ubuntu) worked for me:

```
update.packages(checkBuilt=TRUE, ask=FALSE)
```

Taken from RStudio forum [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/package-digest-was-installed-by-an-r-version-with-different-internals-it-needs-to-be-reinstalled-for-use-with-this-r-version-execution-halted/11438).